# Can a prime of form $4m+1$ be expressed as sum of 2 squares in more than one way?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

It is easy to find dozens of proofs (some of which are elementary or easy to follow) that every prime of the form $4m+1$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares.

> How can one prove that every *prime* of the form $4m+1$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares $p = a^2 + b^2 | a,b \in \Bbb Z^+, a>b$ **in only one way**?

This is easy to verify for primes up to quite a large value but I can't find a proof.

Comment: Most elementary texts on number theory prove this.

Comment: @mathnoob $3$ is not of the from $4m+1$

Comment: very nice discussion of this, also for $mx^2 + ny^2$ with $m,n$ positive and coprime, by Brillhart http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brillhart_Euler_factoring_2009.pdf

Comment: @Will Jagy - Thanks for that reference - very enlightening.

Comment: @will Jagy yes that answers the question.  I have +1 the comment but if you put the proof as an answer it will bury this question; otherwise, perhaps I will do so maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $p$ a prime number of the form $4m+1$. Thus $$p\equiv 1\pmod 4$$
Assume that $p={a^2}+{b^2}={c^2}+{d^2}$ for some $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb {N}$ such that, w.l.o.g. $a>b$ and $c>d$. Our aim is now to show by contradiction, that this follows to $a=c$ and $b=d$:

We now have $$(ad-bc)(ad+bc)={a^2}{d^2}-{b^2}{c^2}=\bigl(p-{b^2\bigr)}{d^2}-{b^2}\bigl(p-{d^2\bigr)}=p\bigl({d^2}-{b^2}\bigr)\equiv 0\pmod p$$
This implies (see [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)) that either $$p|(ad-bc)$$
or $$p|(ad+bc)$$

Let's suppose $p\mid(ad+bc)$. Hence ${a^2},{b^2},{c^2},{d^2}<p$. Thus $a,b,c,d<\sqrt{p}$, which implies that $$0<ad+bc<2p$$
That leads to $ad+bc=p$. However $${p^2}=\Bigl({a^2}+{b^2}\Bigr)\Bigl({c^2}+{d^2}\Bigr)={(ad+bc)^2}+{(ac-bd)^2}={p^2}+{(ac-bd)^2}$$ $$\Rightarrow ac-bd=0$$
which, nevertheless, contradicts the assumption that $a>b$ and $c>d$. This shows, that $p\nmid ({ad+bc})$.

This implies $p\mid ({ad-bc})$. Analugously $$a,b,c,d<\sqrt{p}$$ which implies that $$-p<ad-bc<p \Rightarrow ad=bc$$ Hence $a\mid {bc}$. Note however, that since $p={a^2}+{b^2}$, $a$ and $b$ have to be coprime, so $$a\mid{c}$$
Let $c=xa$. Since $ad=bc$, it follows that $d=xb$

We finally have $$p={a^2}+{b^2}={c^2}+{d^2}={x^2}\bigl({a^2}+{b^2}\bigr)\Rightarrow x=1$$
$$\Rightarrow c=a\quad d=b$$